# Sum a list of numbers in a Function Python

Tags: python

I am a bit stuck in one of my assignment questions. Can someone point out why my sum returns 7 rather than 22?

```
def getEven(list):
   
    even = 0
    odd = 0
    sum = 0
    ratio = 0
    
    
    for nmbr in list:
        if nmbr % 2 == 0:
           even+=1 
        
        else:
            odd+=1  
    sum += nmbr 
    ratio = even/odd  

    return even, odd, sum, ratio


list=[1,2,3,4,5,7]

even, odd, sum, ratio = getEven(list)
dict={'even': even, 'odd':odd, 'sum': sum, 'ratio': ratio}

print(dict)
```

Comment: You're not adding to the sum within the loop. Indent that line.

Comment: That's because `sum += nmbr` is not indented properly. It only had the last `nmbr` value (the value it took in the last loop).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it is not a good idea to name any of your Python variables the same name as a built-in Python function or object. It could cause all sorts of problems in your code. So I would suggest changing the name of your `sum` and your `dict` variable.

Now for your actual question. The problem is that the expression

```
sum += nmbr
```

isn't actually in your for-loop! Be careful of your indents. Here is your code with the correct indentation, which you can see will return sum as 22.

```
def getEven(list):
   
    even = 0
    odd = 0
    sum = 0
    ratio = 0
    
    
    for nmbr in list:
        if nmbr % 2 == 0:
           even+=1 
        else:
            odd+=1  
        sum += nmbr 
    ratio = even/odd  

    return even, odd, sum, ratio


list=[1,2,3,4,5,7]

even, odd, sum, ratio = getEven(list)
dict={'even': even, 'odd':odd, 'sum': sum, 'ratio': ratio}

print(dict) # Prints {'even': 2, 'odd': 4, 'sum': 22, 'ratio': 0}
```

Comment: Typo questions should be closed with that close reason, not answered.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Well, typos in your code are very legitimate mistakes. I don't see what's wrong with answering the OP's question.

Comment: No they're not very legitimate mistakes; that's precisely why there an entire close reason devoted to typos. OP forgot to indent that line. The reason these aren't good questions is because they don't help anyone but the OP, and this site is intended as a database of useful questions and answers, not throwaway public private tutoring.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Well anyway, I just wanted to help the OP. If the question is closed without any answers the OP may never know of his/her mistake.

Comment: -_- As the OP stated, this is an assignment. They're in a class. They most likely have a teacher, and will surely have classmates, not to mention instructional materials. The only way for them to never learn their mistake is to never put a single ounce of effort into it. They just ask here instead of many other more suitable places because here they can get an instant answer with corrected code ready to be copy-pasted, and they don't care that it's an unsuitable question.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Okay, fair enough. Thanks for patiently explaining this to me. So does that mean I should delete my answer?

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip, I have corrected my code variable names. So here is a follow up questions. Why does the ration turn up the correct calculations when it is outside the loop?

Comment: @datagalz Because your assignment of `ratio` doesn't depend on the variable `nmbr`, which is from the for loop.